# XScreenSaver does not turn monitor off in Lubuntu

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, xscreensaver

If I minimize Thunderbird or Firefox or whatever I currently am working on, then leave the system alone it should turn the monitor off after a set number of minutes.

XScreenSaver is not turning off the monitor (however it will dim) if anything is left minimized in the lxpanel.

What is the resolve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a 
    Ubuntu
    “xscreensaver” package
    Bugs
    Bug #992248

Same as the issue I have